# How c++ subscribes float64 message published from rosserial

Tags: ros, c++, rosserial, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to subscribe  some data  which is published from rosserial_arduino  in cpp

### I coded like this in sketch

```
std_msgs::Float64 vx_msg; 

ros::Publisher vx_pub("vx_msg", &vx_msg);

void setup() {

  nh.getHardware() -> setBaud(57600); 

  nh.initNode();

  nh.advertise(vx_pub);

}

void loop() {

  nh.spinOnce();

  vx_msg.data = 1; // publish linear velocity

  vx_pub.publish (&vx_msg);

}
```

This is for calculating odometry .  As I can't use encoder, I have to publish constant velocity which I compute.

I can check that the message is published well because I can watch the data  with '  $ rostopic echo'

so I coded with global function  in .cpp file

##Like this

```
double vel_x;

void vx_odom (const vx_pub::vx_msg &vx_msg)

{

    vel_x = vx_msg.vx.msg.data;

}
```

There are tutorials about how to subscribe string message . But, I don't have idea  if It is Float64 type.

What is the form of subsribing float 64 type data ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217504/how--c++-subscribes--float64-message-published-from-rosserial/) by [Ros_junior](https://answers.ros.org/users/22459/ros_junior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check again the [Subscriber Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node) and try to understand it. Especially read carefully the the paragraph where the commands are described.

Instead of what you did here:

```
void vx_odom (const vx_pub::vx_msg &vx_msg)
```

you have to put in the respective message type into the callback function. So for you it would be:

```
void vx_odom (const std_msgs::Float64::ConstPtr& vx_msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1